# how upgrade from elasticsearch version 5.3.1 to 6.0.0 with updated mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to upgrade elastic search version with updated mapping( i have renamed/added/deleted some field)

how can I migrate data , any reference apprecited

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve that. It depends on the amount of data the cluster holds, whether maintenance downtime is acceptable or not, and do you have backward compatibility issues with the fields names/types.

A simple (but a bit costly) way to upgrade would be to spin up a new cluster with version 6.0 and reindex the data from the old cluster to the new. another method can be to upgrade to latest 5.X version (5.6) and from there do a rolling restart. from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/6.0/upgrading-elastic-stack.html : "Rolling upgrades are supported when upgrading from Elasticsearch 5.6 to 6.0.1"